# the method put boolean in type bundle is not applicable for radio buttons

Tags: android, radio-button, save, instance, preferences

i need to save the instance of my application when the user rotates the screen.I have used toggle button **"inst"** , image button **"play"** and radio button **"sp"**.This is my code:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
         outState.putBoolean("play",play);
         outState.putBoolean("inst", inst);
         outState.putBoolean("sp",sp);         /* shows the error "the method put boolean in 
                                                 type bundle is not applicable for radio buttons"*/          
         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        }
```

what are we supposed to use for radio buttons then? When i googled i got results saying that we have to use preference activity.Then in my case, i have to change all the elements in my current layout.Any other solution would be of much help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to put Boolean values only in Bundle.putBoolean method, whereas you are placing RadioButton, ToggleButton in it. SO instead passing View Objects pass state in this method, by getting isChecked property change your code to following:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
        {
         //outState.putBoolean("play",play);//are you sure its ImageButton if It is, you cant get State  of it in boolean 
         outState.putBoolean("inst", inst.isChecked());
         outState.putBoolean("sp",sp.isChecked());                  
         super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        }
```

Comment: Ya that solved the issue.But then how would you get the value in **restore instance** ? with the property again? but then it is not working.                                                sp.isChecked()= savedInstanceState.getBoolean("sp");

Comment: you need to restore state by sp.setChecked(savedInstanceState.getBoolean("sp"));

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `isChecked()` method of radio button like in the code as follows,

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
{
            outState.putBoolean("play",play.isChecked());
            outState.putBoolean("inst", inst.isChecked());
            outState.putBoolean("sp",sp.isChecked());      
           super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check your Radio button `sp` using `isChecked()` method.